# Skip class selector

Tags: css

Got a question I hope someone can help me with.

Example code:

```
<div class="Main">
 <div class="Variable">
  <div class="Target">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to target the "Target" class within the "Main" class. So if it wasn't for the "Variable" class I could use this:

```
.Main .Target {}
```

However, the "Variable" class is in between. I can't specify the "Variable" class, as the class is variable and changes depending on the layout of the site.

Is there any way I can still target the "Target" class within the "Main" class, without knowing the "Variable" class, i.e. skipping it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried `.Main .Target {}`?

Comment: You are already doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Main .Target {}` selects all the `.Target` that are children of `.Main`, which is what I am assuming you want.

If you have other styles that are overriding it, or you want to just select the `.Target` that are direct children of `.Variable` just select like

```
.Main > div > .Target{}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this easily:

```
.Main .Target {}
```

It matches all descendants, not only direct. (https://jsfiddle.net/LqheL0u1/)

You could not however use the following, which you probably thought acted like the above:

```
.Main > .Target {}
```

As this would select direct descendants, so called children.